# Ruby on Rails - sqlite 3 rake migrations not updating the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, database-migration

I am using RoR (3.2.2) and SQLite 3 (1.3.5).  When I initially generate a model I am able to successfully create a database.  However, whenever I try to use the migration generator it appears to not have any issues in the command line (no errors), but when I check the database nothing has updated or changed.

For example, I create this database:

```
$ rails generate model User name:string email:string
```

db/migrate/[timestamp]_create_users.rb

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And I run a migration:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

So far so good, I check my database using SQLite Database Browser and everything looks as it should.

Then if I want to add an index:

```
$ rails generate migration add_index_to_users_email
```

db/migrate/[timestamp]_add_index_to_users_email.rb

```
class AddIndexToUsersEmail < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :users, :email, unique: true
  end
end
```

I run a migration:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

And command line gives me the following:

> bundle exec rake db:migrate
>   ==  AddIndexToUsersEmail: migrating ===========================================
>   ==  AddIndexToUsersEmail: migrated (0.0000s) ==================================

However, when I check my database using SQLite Database Browser it isn't updated.  I get the same results if I try to add new columns to the table, etc.  The only way I have been able to do migrations is manually updating the database using the SQLite Database Browser.  Any help as to why it is not working through Rails and the command line would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.0'

group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.8.1'
gem 'annotate', '~> 2.4.1.beta'
end

group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.4'
gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.0'

group :test do
gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end

group :production do
gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

Database.yml

```
development:
adapter: sqlite3
database: db/development.sqlite3
pool: 5
timeout: 5000

test:
adapter: sqlite3
database: db/test.sqlite3
pool: 5
timeout: 5000

production:
adapter: sqlite3
database: db/production.sqlite3
pool: 5
timeout: 5000
```

Example of successfully adding a column:

```
 rails generate migration add_password_digest_to_users password_digest:string
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20120318235656_add_password_digest_to_users.rb
 $ subl db/migrate/[timestamp]_add_password_digest_to_users.rb
 $ bundle exec rake db:migrate
 ==  AddPasswordDigestToUsers: migrating =======================================
 -- add_column(:users, :password_digest, :string)   -> 0.0008s
 ==  AddPasswordDigestToUsers: migrated (0.0009s) ==============================
```

Example of unsuccessfully adding a column:

```
 $ rails generate migration add_remember_token_to_users
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20120319010623_add_remember_token_to_users.rb
 $ subl db/migrate/[timestamp]_add_remember_token_to_users.rb
 $ bundle exec rake db:migrate
 ==  AddRememberTokenToUsers: migrating ========================================
 ==  AddRememberTokenToUsers: migrated (0.0000s) ===============================
```

Notice when it fails to update the database the migration time is zero. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what happens is you get the syntax slightly wrong (it's insanely tricky) then you get an empty migration which doesn't do anything.

I would double check that the actual migration file has add column.  I often end up manually putting the actual change (or up/down) in.

As t Harrison says, adding an index is more subtle - as you sure it doesn't get added if you refresh the sqlite borwser.  The examples you gave that worked... are to add columns...

Comment: I did some testing and if I change `$rails generate migration add_remember_token_to_users` to `$rails generate migration add_remember_token_to_users remember_token:string` then it works. I'm still not sure on the correct syntax on the index though. Those are still not working for me.  The add_index example above is from [http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial?version=3.2#cha:static_pages] but I can't get it to actually appear in the database.

Comment: Generating a migration usually only creates a file with a special name, and the shell of a class and some empty methods; in some cases it can also generate the code based on the name you provide.  Check the migration files (in `app/db/migrate/`) -- typically you'll have to add the code manually.  This is all well documented at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem undoing the last migration with

```
rails destroy migration add_index_to_users_email
```

Then I closed my terminals to ensure that all db connections were closed, then I run

```
rake db:reset
```

Finally, running the same commands again

```
rails generate migration add_index_to_users_email
```

Updating the file with the same content and running

```
rake db:migrate
```

All the same commands and files that were not working before now worked at all (for me).

I hope this works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

The output you posted from the add index example shows that the migration is indeed running ... but you report it's not actually doing anything.  Try `bundle exec rake:db rollback` (with optional `STEP=n` to go more than one step back).  This really should "just work", and a case of an index might be a little subtle -- try adding a column or something (which you said you have done, but, just to be sure).  Does it really not work?  How can you tell?

Comment: Yeah, it is strange. Sometimes it works adding columns and sometimes it doesn't.  The one thing I noticed, the times it doesn't work the time of the migration is always 0.0000s, while when it does work there is some time elasped (i.e. 0.0009s). I added a column password_digest successfully but failed to add the column remember_token (I'll add these examples above).

Comment: As per my comment to Michael Durant's answer -- the first example provides Rails enough information to generate the migration file and the necessary code; the second does not.