# ROR Tutorail - SQLite3 DB Doesn't Update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

Rails Tutorial Michael H. (rails -v 4.2.2)

Objective:  Get schema.rb and add_column_password_digest to update and show on SQLite3 browser; however, it seems to not update the SQLite3 browser.

```
 $ rails generate migration add_password_digest_to_users password_digest:string
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20160109023342_add_password_digest_to_users.rb
```

(The command above runs fine, meaning it does indeed create the migration.)

```
class AddPasswordDigestToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
add_column :users, :password_digest, :string
end
end
```

(The code above, is the actual migration file created by the previous command.)

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
== 20160109023342 AddPasswordDigestToUsers: migrating ====================
-- add_column(:users, :password_digest, :string)
-> 0.0096s
== 20160109023342 AddPasswordDigestToUsers: migrated (0.0097s) ================
```

(Then I run the command above)

As shown, it should theoretically add_column to sqlite3 db right?

Also, I will include the schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160109023342) do

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.string   "email"
t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
t.string   "password_digest"
end

add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true

end
```

(The version is equal to that of the add_password_digest_to_users.rb  but yet schema migration in the sqlite3 db does not update either.)

Yes, I have tried everything from making sure syntax was right, running this command 
    rake db:migrate VERSION=20160109023342

and last but not least checking out this thread [Ruby on Rails - sqlite 3 rake migrations not updating the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763331/ruby-on-rails-sqlite-3-rake-migrations-not-updating-the-database)

Lastly, I do have the gemfile copied right off the tutorial correctly.. check it out

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end
```

From the info given and given that I also copied Michael's tutorial exactly, what am I missing or adding on that is causing the sqlite3 db to not update or dsplay any of the new commands??

Thank You.

Comment: If you open the database file with the `sqlite3` CLI tool and say `.schema users`, what do you get?

Comment: I do not get anything in return once in sqlite3 CLI tool and input .schema users... Anything else?   I appreciate the help.

Comment: Did you open the right database file? It should say something.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried continuing onto the next section, which instructs you to install the `bcrypt` gem?

Your schema.rb file looks fine to me. I just finished this chapter in the book and my file looks exactly the same. I didn't encounter any issues. Is Rails giving you a specific error?

Comment: No it isn't giving any error.. And before starting project, I downloaded all of the gems needed for the project.  So, I do have the 'bcrypt' gem installed.. Any other reason?  Thanks..